# Two ListView in ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have put two listview in scrollview but i have a problem, when i put item in the first listview the second listview will be scrollable. I want that the whole area will be scrollable and not scrollview, How i do? the first scrollview is listViewEventiAggiunti the second listViewEventi.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/activity_lista__eventi"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padBottom"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padLeft"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padRight"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padTop"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        tools:context="com.example.fra87.eudroid.activity_class.Lista_Eventi">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:queryHint="Evento"
                android:id="@+id/cercaEvento"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutEventi">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:hint="Nome Evento"
                android:textSize="22dip"
                android:id="@+id/editText_nome_evento_composto"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewEventiAggiunti"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />



        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/separatore_liste"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>



            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewEventi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cercaEvento"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want scroll entire area, i don't want scroll on listview, when i put item in listview the area increases and i scroll entire area is possible?

Comment: I don't get you. You want every ListView to be scrollable separately or you them to show all of their items and then ScrollView become scrollable?

Comment: why you want to do this implementation would be helpful to share a screen shot to suggest other way because this is a very bad practice

Comment: @shadoWalker i want show all of their items and then ScrollView become scrollable. How i do?

Comment: Any Solution? please

Comment: What is your project minimum sdk?

Comment: Api level 16 why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Since your minimum SDK version is 16, you have 2 solution for your problem.

First is use this library:
https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/ExpandableHeightListView
This library makes you able to expand your ListViews to full height and then only your ScrollView will be scrollable.

Second solution is to use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView and then use RecyclerView instead of ListView. Then you should only disable nestedScrolling for your RecyclerView.

Both solutions will give you your desire behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiple type item for listview](https://www.google.co.id/search?q=android%20listview%20multiple%20types) and simplified your layout to become like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/activity_lista__eventi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padBottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padLeft"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padRight"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padTop"
                tools:context="com.example.fra87.eudroid.activity_class.Lista_Eventi"
    >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/cercaEvento"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:queryHint="Evento"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_nome_evento_composto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cercaEvento"
        android:hint="Nome Evento"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separatore_liste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_nome_evento_composto"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewEventi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separatore_liste"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I can't use this, there are an other solution?